# I need to darken an image using javascript within html

Tags: javascript, html, css

css

```css
.image-darken {
  transition: 1s;
  filter: brightness (10%);
}
```

javascript

```js
const portfolioItems = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio-item-wrapper');

portfolioItems.forEach(portfolioItem => {
  portfolioItem.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    console.log(portfolioItem.childNodes[1].classList);
    portfolioItem.childNodes[1].classList.add('image-darken');
  });
});
```

HTML

```html
<div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
  <div class="portfolio-img-background"
       style="background-image:url(images/portfolio1.jpg"></div>

  <div class="img-text-wrapper">
    <div class="logo-wrapper">
      <img src="images/quip.png">
    </div>
    <div class="subtitle">
      I built the Quip Ecommerce platform, named a Top 25 Invention by Time
      Magazine in 2016.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to use javascript to make it so that when I put my cursor over the image, it darkens in one second. And when my cursor leaves, it lightens in one second. I have many `portfolio-item-wrapper` elements. I want to use javascript because I want this to be my introduction to javascript. I am following a tutorial on youtube.

This is the tutorial [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bMdjkfvONE). The part with javascript comes in at about 1:14:00.

This is what the website looks like so far:

[image: my website so far]

Please help me and dumb it down for me, i just started learning to code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you're aiming for is typically achieved without any JavaScript, by using the `:hover` [CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover). Taking a non-JavaScript "pure CSS" approach generally allows for simpler solution that is more maintainable in the long run.

In your case, a pure CSS approach is possible by removing your JavaScript and by applying the following changes to your CSS:

```css
/*
Not needed
.image-darken {
  transition: 1s;
  filter: brightness (10%);
}
*/

.portfolio-item-wrapper {
  /* Add transition rule to filter property of the item wrapper */
  transition: filter 1s;
}

/* Add styling that applies when the user "hovers" the element. The 
    "hover" will cause the filtering to be applied to this element */
.portfolio-item-wrapper:hover {
  filter: brightness(10%);
}

/* Added for snippet - not needed in your code */
.portfolio-img-background {
  min-height:5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
  <div class="portfolio-img-background"
       style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/150)"></div>
  <div class="img-text-wrapper">
    <div class="subtitle">
      I built the Quip Ecommerce platform, named a Top 25 Invention by Time
      Magazine in 2016.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you really want to take a scripted approach to this, then you could do the following:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio-item-wrapper')
.forEach(item => {

  /* Get background element of this item */
  const background = item.querySelector('.portfolio-img-background')

  /* Add image-darken class to background element on hover event */
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    background.classList.add('image-darken');
  });
  
  /* Add image-darken class to background element on hover end */
  item.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    background.classList.remove('image-darken');
  });
});
```

```css
/* Apply transition to the background element of portfolio item */
.portfolio-item-wrapper .portfolio-img-background {
  transition: filter 1s;
}

/* Define image darkening */
.image-darken {
  filter: brightness(10%);
}

/* Added for snippet - not needed in your code */
.portfolio-img-background {
  min-height:5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-item-wrapper">
  <div class="portfolio-img-background"
       style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/150)"></div>
  <div class="img-text-wrapper">
    <div class="subtitle">
      I built the Quip Ecommerce platform, named a Top 25 Invention by Time
      Magazine in 2016.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! i followed your advice on only using CSS, i really appreciate it. The original code you sent me darkened the image background the logo on top, and the subtitle so in css i put  .portfolio-img-background after all the .portfolio-item-wrapper's. Thank you so much!

Comment: @7urney if you have found this answer helpful please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the grey tick to the left of the answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to overlay the image with a grey overlay that shall enable you to have dark effect on the image in the background.

```
.layer {
    background-color: rgba(248, 247, 216, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}  
.card-title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 36%;
    font-size: 2.0em;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
  }
.card {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

**HTMl Patch**

```
<div class="card" id="card">
  <img src="{{Path_to_featured_image}}"/>
  <div class="card-title" id="card-title">{{Heading_or_slug}}</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$( "#card-title" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "layer" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "layer" );
  }
);
```

you can also set unset the classes on realtime using Javascript if you want to control it dynamically using various parameters like id, class or even tag to select the effected element.

Answer (score -1):

I advise you use JavaScript addEventListener 'hover', function(){getEl......ById....style.opacity=0.5}